# Type for only subclasses of a class

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

If I have a base class and multiple sub classes that inherit from this base, e.g:

```
class Message {
      constructor(public text: string) {}
}

class MessageA extends Message {
    msgType: string = 'A';

    constructor(
        public text: string,
        public aData: string
    ) {
        super(text);
    }
}

class MessageB extends Message {
    msgType: string = 'B';

    constructor(
        public text: string,
        public bData: number
    ) {
        super(text);
    }
}
```

… is it possible to create a type that only admits the sub classes?

I want something like

```
type Msg = MessageA | MessageB;
```

… that would allow me to write

```
const show = (msg: Msg): void => {
    switch (msg.msgType) {
        case 'A':
            return console.log(`${msg.text}: ${msg.aData}`);
        case 'B':
            return console.log(`${msg.text}: ${msg.bData}`);
    }
}
```

However, the code above gives me this error:

```
Property 'aData' does not exist on type 'Msg'.
  Property 'aData' does not exist on type 'MessageB'.
```

If I change the type to be the following, `show` works again:

```
type Msg = ({msgType: 'A'} & MessageA)
         | ({msgType: 'B'} & MessageB);
```

But if I then call `show` with a new `MessageB`…

```
show(new MessageB('hello', 300));
```

… I get this error:

```
Argument of type 'MessageB' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Msg'.
  Type 'MessageB' is not assignable to type '{ msgType: "B"; } & MessageB'.
    Type 'MessageB' is not assignable to type '{ msgType: "B"; }'.
      Types of property 'msgType' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"B"'.(2345)
```

What is a good way to create a type for the subclasses of a base class?

The goal here is to ensure that a handler will inspect the type of the object it was passed before it can access any fields (that aren't in the base class) and also ensure that the `switch` is exhaustive for when future sub classes are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want `Msg` to be a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), with `msgType` as a *discriminant* property.

Unfortunately you have annotated the `msgType` properties on `MessageA` and `MessageB` to be `string`, and `string` is not a valid discriminant property type.  Discriminants must be unit types that only accept a single value, like `undefined` or `null`, or a string/numeric/boolean [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).

Instead of `string`, you want them to be of the string literal types `"A"` and `"B"`, respectively.  You can do this either by explicitly annotating them as such, or by marking them as [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#readonly), which will cause the compiler to infer literal types for them:

```
class MessageA extends Message {
  readonly msgType = 'A';
  // (property) MessageA.msgType: "A"

  constructor(
    public text: string,
    public aData: string
  ) {
    super(text);
  }
}

class MessageB extends Message {
  readonly msgType = 'B';
  // (property) MessageB.msgType: "B"

  constructor(
    public text: string,
    public bData: number
  ) {
    super(text);
  }
}
```

Once you do this, the narrowing in your `show()` function will just work:

```
const show = (msg: Msg): void => {
  switch (msg.msgType) {
    case 'A':
      return console.log(`${msg.text}: ${msg.aData}`); // okay
    case 'B':
      return console.log(`${msg.text}: ${msg.bData}`); // okay
  } 
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCmUwHN7QN4FgBQ1rAHsA7CAFwCcBXYUg8gCgAdKAjEAS2GlPgA9SAXNDLl2RZAEoM0AL4452HKEgwESVAEFofHkQAmqxBBRosuaOXhg9xEAE9oAWwjIAKncZoAvNADkG3wBuHDwAelDoJnICT3JSOyk1Y00AOmc3D3ghACINbJwQ-GIRaloGQrxmNk5uHSERMWQAGgroKo4uMAARMFIweopGwqkzPDwISlj6Hn4JYPMFBSVwKDgjEwAhbX54fUN1U0LLa1sHdPdPaB9fDaDC8MjGaNj4xPXUDbSXC6zobI38opzIQSBRSnR6K12jUZoJhINxC1zJVWB1oCwen0hERKI4WPByMMMK0JlNYXNCosCth4pdYC4rmsDloAD5M5LwDbzakgsjCAAWBAA7oz6OkhPTJEIAG4Edh6K4APmJ5ggQvYpGA-Mi6S+GU8I1awEgaH8vgErTwllIlHIRCKJAIIHgKRABGQ9AABgASdC62EyIS+3XdXpgGSeubQB4EADWYDsRpNfluFuRY2ttvtvKdLrdHp9fpcKQDQaLyBSGLDEajMfjiYW8hwQA)